# SSRS 2012: "The report execution has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 and received this error without any known cause: `The report execution eqaiekfzmk2snc55y0zrow55 has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)`.

While I have found other posts describing problem through Google searches, the resolutions did not help me:

- Restarting SQL Server, SQL Server Agent, and SQL Server Reporting services
- Increasing the Execution Timeout through SQL Server Management Studio when connected to the Reporting server
- Adding `rs:ClearSession` to the URL querystring (and trying IE, Chrome, and Firefox)
- Redeploying after each troubleshooting step and retesting
- I looked in the Reporting Services log file folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles` but I see the datestamp is over two months old and I could see nothing related to the symptom.
- I looked looked in ExecutionLog3 and did not see anything related to the symptom.  `use ReportServer; select * from ExecutionLog3;`

To find out what did work, I verified that:

- The query and results are sound, as seen in Management Studio
- I can preview the report in Data Tools on the server
- I can view the report when remoting into the server

I only see the error when viewing the page from outside the server.  This is a relatively lightweight query and result set, so I cannot believe that this problem has anything to do with execution timeouts.

I changed the name of the file and redeployed. I am able to see that report now, but this isn't a true resolution because I still don't know what is truly causing the problem and how to fix it. If the symptom appears again, I can't keep changing the filename and redeploy.

Is there a way to get a better idea of what is happening? A specific log file or a property I need to change?

**Update:**

I thought I had this problem worked out, but apparently not. I found nothing useful in the error logs: only a restatement of the same error message visible in the browser.  When I redeploy (using SQL Server Data Tools), the error goes away... for a few hours or until the next day, when I need to redeploy to make the error go away.

[image: The error message]

Comment: You can look at the [Report Server Execution Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159110(v=sql.120).aspx) and see if there's anything good in there.  I have not verified that these still exist in 2012, but they were sometimes useful in 2008 r2.

Comment: I did not know about the execution logs. This will help me in other areas unrelated to this question. Unfortunately, it does not help me diagnose this problem.

Comment: You may find more verbose information in the SSRS log files at <SQL_SSRS_INSTALL_PATH>\ReportingServices\LogFiles -->C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: How are you viewing the report - Report Manager? Sharepoint? a custom web app using ReportViewer control? If it's in a browser, which browser version are you using?

Comment: It is a browser. I tried all of the most updated versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: @lrb -- I re-discovered that SQL Server was installed on a different drive, and so the log files were also saved on that different drive. You had the right idea all along -- I was just looking at the wrong drive letter.  I found a whole set of log files with names like `ReportServerService__08_19_2015_13_30_59.log`. This answers my question, because I can open the log files and find more details about the raised errors with a word search. Do you want to post it as an answer and get the credit?

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question but I had this problem recently and it turned out to be a bad session cookie. The cookies session-id matched the guid in the error message and once I deleted the cookie all worked fine after that. The report at one point had been configured to cache a temporary copy

[image: SSRS Report Processing Options]

but that had since been turned off (however, the problem existed before that had been turned off so it may not be relevant).

Hopefully this answer will help someone else save the hour I spent figuring it out in my environment :)

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. In our end we are using Chrome so I went to settings > (click on advanced) > Content Settings > Cookies > See all cookies and site data > [reporting services url] > [report name cookie]. This was happening locally so my reporting services url was simply localhost and  the cookie was called exactly as the report.

Comment: Likewise for me - I edited the report with report builder on the server, saved it and it stopped working until I cleared all cache in the browser and all worked again. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This might help someone.

In my case, The report url had **trailing spaces** (a silly mistake) which caused this.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem!

Comment: In my case, it was a report that had run fine before (same URL); a second try and it worked - so it is sometimes obviously a transitory problem. If you get it, wait a second, think positive, smile sweetly, and try again (actually, just trying again was all I did, and it worked).

Comment: You saved my time mate.. :)

Answer (score 8):

I've added `&rs:Command=ClearSession` to the end of my url and works fine with me.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in a different answer you can clear the session which usually resolves this issue.

If you have a question mark in your URL already then add the following to the end.

```
&rs:Command=ClearSession
```

If you do not have one then you need to add the following to the end.

```
?rs:Command=ClearSession
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, it was for an existing report that had been working correctly. However, the Report Builder had been open for some time in another window while I was working on something else, and I hadn't saved my work (I was applying a filter, and didn't want to save my changes with my test filter). It occurred to me that since the report HAD been working, but it had been sitting idle, it might have gone stale. I opened the Dataset Properties, clicked Query Designer, then "Run Query". The Query Designer then got a fresh request from the data source. I closed the Dataset Properties window and clicked "Run", and my report was again displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had no trailing space.

Some people had luck with clearing Session.Keys of "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy"

I solved it by Session.Clear in the global.asax

Answer (score 0):

For us, the error appeared trying to run a report on an SSRS 2016 server using Internet Explorer 11. The user had created a bookmark that linked directly to the report. What may have happened: IE preserves cookies and temporary internet files for favorites to "help them load faster". The user may have initially ran the report, then created the bookmark to the report which contained session information.

To fix: Delete the bookmark, then cleared browser history in IE (CTL+SHIFT+DEL) being sure to **uncheck** "Preserve Favorites website data".